# I can't get my rewrite rule to work properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make this:

```
www.amazingjokes.com/cache/search.php?term=programming
```

to go to this:

```
wwww.amazingjokes.com/popular/programming
```

But I can not get it to work properly. I tried stuff like

```
RewriteRule ^cache/search.php?term=(.*)$ /popular/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRule doesn't receive the query string, what it's actually receiving is just the path to the file. So while you're going to `/cache/search.php?term=programming`, what it's actually receiving is just `/cache/search.php`.

You can, however, use a RewriteCond on the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^term=(.*)$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^/cache/search.php$ /search/%1      [NC,L,R=301]
```